# How close are Leap 15.3 and SLE 15 SP3? Can I use one's rpms with the other?

Tags: rpm, opensuse, distributions, sles, compatibility

Apologies if this is a stoopid question.

With some effort I have managed to install openSUSE Leap 15.3 on my laptop. As you may know 15.3 is rather different to earlier releases in that it apparently "uses binaries from" SLE 15 SP3. Unfortunately, another difference appears to be that many packages which were there all the way up to 15.2 appear to be missing, I've seen the line [There is no official package available for openSUSE Leap 15.3](https://software.opensuse.org/package/llvm) (this example is llvm) way more often than I care.

So my question: Is it generally possible / safe to use SLE 15 SP3 repositories instead? (I see that one of the automatic update repositories is indeed SLE.) I daren't simply try for fear of damaging my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not mix packages from OpenSuse and Suse Enterprise, if it's not crucial. Adding repositories would mean to actually have the system licensed and being able to reach the SLE repos. I see there is a package for llvm for Leap 15.2, which should work on 15.3. Grab the binary package and install it.

Comment: Thanks! Do I understand correctly that even if the SLE repos worked I wouldn't be able to use them as they are not freely accessible?

Comment: Enterprise Linux systems like SLE or RHEL use a subscription model, where you have to register a system to make the repositories accessible on the system. Suse uses the so called SUSEConnect binary to subscribe. Furthermore, packages for SLE SP13 are specifically built with depencendies for this distro release. It *might* work on Leap, but that depends on the package complexity, and I've made the mistake of mixing distro release packages more times than I can remember.

Answer (score 2):

Do not mix packages from different distributions. Even using packages from another, near, version of the distribution will probably lead to endless grief.

- Look around for unofficial repositories for your distribution, like collections of software maintained by user groups, personal sandboxes, whatever.
- Sites like https://rpmfind.net can be of help, pointing at package sources.
- Grab the *source* package for a similar distribution (see the previous point), and build your own *binary* package from it. It might require tweaking (update/fix dependencies, adjust configuration files or filesystem layout, delete/modify/add local patches). Bonus: You can this way also update to a newer version of the package.
- Just punt and install the software from source (strongly suggested to do it systemwide under `/usr/local` or locally for your account only).

Note that any of the above, specially if you replace/update some central package, is guaranteed to void your warranty (as it exists ;-), and gives you a chimaera system that will be hard to debug for people familiar with the vanilla system.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your advice. I can handle option 4  as long as it is a simple ./configure make make install but am screwed if anything goes wrong. Option 3 is a bit out of my league; I tried it once (because option 4 wouldn't work because of suse lib64 handling) and it was a proper nightmare.

Comment: @loopywalt, don't try creating your own RPM from scratch, start with the source RPM from elsewhere (a near distribution, compare to a similar current package). Any weird library (or configuration, or whatever) handling will be in there.